# Is there a way to add a delay within an if statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have an if statement set a variable to true, then set it to false shortly after. Is this possible, and what is the best way to do this? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: absolutely that is possible, but what that *means* is hugely contextual; what is the "variable" here? a local? a field on an instance being accessed by multiple threads? something else? would something like a manual/auto-reset-event be preferable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to C# and coding in general. I'm not entirely sure what kind of variable it is, as it is being used through Unity's built-in animation system, but I'm trying to use it to animate an object. Basically, when I click my mouse, this variable will be set to true and will initiate the animation. After a short delay, I want it to be set to false so I can repeat the animation again.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1306123/do-something-after-animation-finishes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Threading;
Thread.Sleep(1); # will add asleep of 1ms -> 1 mili-sec
```

EDIT:

Do note that this is in no way hinting to use the specified delay. Nor is it suggesting to use static sleep. That generally always slows down the application. Second to what @Marc suggested.

You would want to evolve your solutioning to event-based structure going forward.

Comment: OP has now added context about this being a unity animation scenario; adding a 1s delay between frames may be... inadvisable :)